# É possivel ativar o menu de contexto do Sistema Operacional em aplicação swing?

Tags: java, swing

Há algum tempo eu percebi que não é possível chamar o menu de contexto do sistema operacional em componentes do swing, apesar de ser possível efetuar ações padrões de teclado(como copiar, colar, recortar, selecionar) nestes componentes sem ter que implementar nada adicional.

- Por que o menu de contexto do sistema não funciona dentro de aplicações em swing?
- Há alguma forma de ativá-lo ou somente implementando este menu utilizando os próprios componentes do swing?

Comment: Acredito que apenas utilizando os componeres do Swing, o link abaixo mostra como implementar.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O que acontece é que os Sistemas Operacionais possuem recursos nativos para criação de janelas, menus, etc, que não são portáveis entre eles, ou seja, se você criar uma janela utilizando uma linguagem  no Windows utilizando os recursos disponíveis do S.O. o mesmo funcionará apenas no Windows, o mesmo ocorre para o Linux. Para acessar recursos nativos você pode utilizar componentes AWT.

O Swing surgiu como uma solução para permitir a portabilidade de software entre vários S.O. bastando que o Sistema Operacional tenha uma máquina virtual Java instalada.

O Swing constrói janelas e menus que são interpretados pela máquina virtual Java, não utilizam recursos nativos dos Sistemas Operacionais.

Você pode saber um pouco mais sobre AWT x Swing no link a seguir: http://www.devmedia.com.br/awt-x-swing-codigo-nativo-x-codigo-interpretado/3212